# Unknown Bittorrent Message

Tags: bittorrent

I have been receiving an odd/unknown message while attempting to communicate with some bittorrent peers.  In this particular case I am in the middle of downloading pieces and all of a sudden this new/odd message pops up in front of a piece response.The message is odd because it doesn't appear to follow the protocol, all messages are supposed to look like this

'`<length prefix><message ID><payload>`'

length prefix is 4 bytes, message id is 1 byte and the payload.  I am including a capture to show what I mean, on line 509 of the capture you will
see a request for a piece, on line 510 you will see the beginning of the response.

The first 4 bytes of the response are 00 00 00 00, ie 0 length message (Which is causing me issues), the next 4 bytes are the actual length of the message which is 30. The actual response to the piece request starts on line 513, so I get the piece I was requesting but this new/odd message is messing me up.  I'm certain I can find a workaround but I would really like to understand what this means.

Also, I have no idea what the actual message means, and cannot find any information about it anywhere.

Here is the Wireshark capture.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Agj06pa-wu0tnFqsYn_KnHmVz3x2

Comment: It is not a binary it is a Wireshark capture

Comment: Ah, my bad. Might want to put that in there, possibly also show a screen capture of Wireshark's output, for those who don't want to download the file to view its contents.

Comment: that link is not very developer-friendly, I can't wget it

Comment: It's a link from my OneDrive, not sure why wget will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from packet 510:

```
0000   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1e 14 01 64 35 3a 61 64 64  ..........d5:add
0010   65 64 36 3a 63 f2 7a 48 17 f4 37 3a 64 72 6f 70  ed6:c.zH..7:drop
0020   70 65 64 30 3a 65                                ped0:e
```

`00 00 00 00` 4 bytes **keep-alive** message

`00 00 00 1e` message length 30 bytes
`14` message type **extended** message (BEP10)
`01` extended message ID = 1 as specified by the previous extension handshake: **ut_pex**

`64 35 3a 61 64 64 65 64 36 3a 63 f2 7a 48 17 f4 37 3a 64 72 6f 70 70 65 64 30 3a 65 
d5:added6:c.zH..7:dropped0:e`
**ut_pex** message data (bencoded)

```
d
 5:added
  6:c.zH..
 7:dropped
  0:
e
```

**ut_pex** message data (bencoded with added white space)

Comment: Ah, keep-alive, thanks.  Still don't get what the extended message means,

Comment: Then, why are you indicating in your extension handshake that your client support ut_pex?!

Answer (score 1):

> The first 4 bytes of the response are 00 00 00 00, ie 0 length message (Which is causing me issues)

The [bittorrent spec](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) says

> Messages of length zero are keepalives, and ignored.